# Starting program from address memory different to 0x0000

Tags: startup, cortex-m

I have simple program where as usual the program is located at the memory 0x0000, and the data is located at 0x20100000 as shown below.

[image]

when I run the simulator and press botton "reset", the code is located almost at the beginning and runs well.

[image]

However, I need the program start from the memory address 0xF0000 and executed the program (because I have important data that must be stored between the address 0x0 and location of the program 0xF0000). So in the dialog "option of target" I changed the start memory address for the code to 0xF0000, but when I simulate I can see that the program is stored at 0xF000 but the pogram counter is stuck at memory adress 0x0.

I read about the scatter file , but it seems to me that is not enough, should add code in the startup file? How can I set the `Reset_Handler` in order to make the program counter begin from 0xF0000?

---

More details:
I am working with a cortex-M1 on a FPGA. The VTOR register is not implemented. In the FPGA board i have the spi-flash memory where i store the FPGA bitstream configuration file.
If i store the bitstream file into the spi-flash memory at the address 0x0 , The FPGA works without any problem, but i couldnt make it works if i store the bitstream at different address then 0x0.

The cortex-M1 allows to choose internal memory (SRAM) for instructions and data, also to use spi-flash external memory using a AHB-SPI-FLASH block, but i can choose just one of them.

I stored the binary file (firmware) into the spi-flash memory at the address 0x0 , and a download the bitstream file to the FPGA (not into the flash memory). Everything work perfectly, the instructions are executed from the spi-flash memory itself.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The ARMv6M and ARMv7M architectures define reset value of the register SCB_VTOR as zero.  This means that at reset the vector table must be located at address zero.  You are not allowed to use the scatter file or linker script to put anything else at this address at boot time.

At the release of reset, the word at address zero is loaded by the processor to set the initial value of the stack pointer, and the word after that (address 4) is loaded to set the initial value of the program counter (usually called Reset_Handler).

After reset, you can use some code to change the value of the VTOR register. This will cause all subsequent vector reads (for interrupts etc) to be offset by that value.  You could then if you wanted copy something else into the space at address zero, assuming that there is a writeable memory there.

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about regular situation where memory at 0x00000000 is Flash, then you can't do it very easily, or even at all. The first 100-ish (typical; up to 256 = MSP + 15 Exceptions + 240 IRQs) words of flash are the vector table and is not usable for code or data, and the first word of flash is always loaded into MSP on power on, and the second word contains reset handler address (+1 because architecture).

Here are some random thoughts on this.

The simplest way to go about it is to place everything you need after the vector table. This is the most rational, in my opinion, way. And default one too.

Another way is to move vector table at runtime. You copy vector table contents to the new location, then you change vector table offset. In this order, so that at all times you have interrupts set correctly.

After you moved vector table, you can re-write flash at runtime, but it seems like a flash-ruining idea. Besides, you would be re-writing it with some data you wanted to place there in the first place, so this data is already somewhere in Flash (and possibly RAM) at the time of doing it. So this actually looks like a pretty complicated way to waste system resources and kill flash at the same time.

I also have another crazy idea of only filling initial vector table only with MSP and reset handler, and in the reset handler you just move vector table and set all handlers there (but you'll have to assign IRQ handlers manually to vector table there). Then you can use flash start except for the first two words without having to re-write flash at runtime. You'll have to manually manage vector table in RAM, which may be tedious. It also uses precious and limited RAM. And if you don't need to change vector table at runtime - change interrupt handlers' associations with their respective interrupts - then it also sounds like a waste of resources.

To be honest, I think you should just put the data/code at Flash Start + 256 words (universal cortex-m solution) or right after the last IRQ vector (MCU-specific solution, but saves Flash, because typically vector table is ~100 words and not 256). I don't see how any of vector table mess could be beneficial here. Sounds like unnecessary complication. This problem is easier to solve by having data you need in another place. All other solutions seem to have serious drawbacks and add unnecessary complexity to the system without any benefit other than "I can read my data from address 0x00000000 instead of address 0x00001000". At the end of the day, why would specific address matter, as long as its properly aligned.

You can place your executable code anywhere you want, but unless you have a very specific reason as to why you would move the vector table from 0x00000000 to somewhere else, it's best to just not touch it and not obfuscate own program.

EDIT: if you want to place executable code after some address, you need to indicate that .text section goes there. Then all executable code will be placed there, and the reset handler address (+1) will be automatically placed into the 2nd word of the flash, and the main() and everything else will be after the desired address. Just make sure you don't try to manipulate data in Flash like in RAM.

Comment: Thanks @Tom V and Ilya for your help. I have to store the bitstream into flash memory at the address 0x0 and try to make that the cortex-M1  boots  from a different address than 0x0. Is it possible? How the Cortex-M3 boots from the address 0x800...0? 

Another idea is try to add in this block an offset address in the block AHB-SPI-FLASH.

Comment: Unfortunately, what you want to do seems weird/impractical/impossible. Your Flash exists at two addresses at the same time. One is 0x00000000 (if BOOT pins are set for "normal boot"), with Flash reads having their own dedicated path to core, but also at 0x08000000, which is Flash on the bus that MCU shares with all its peripherals. Re-writing flash at runtime sounds like a bad idea if it's not a once-a-year software update. In either case, you really cannot have something at 0x00000000 (it's read only), you can write only to 0x08000000 (but you can read it from 0x00000000 and 0x08000000).

Comment: The only adequate option here is not to use the start of the flash. Leave it for the vector table and don't complicate stuff much more than you have to. A lot of headache with little to no gain (if not loss). I mean, what does it matter if your data has some offset from the start of the Flash. Is there a specific reason other than aesthetic feelings of having something at 0x00000000?

Comment: The main reasons were that 1) 32KB that FPGA offers it wasn't enough, and I wanted to used the flash memory as the external instruction memory, and for data would be used the FPGA's ram blocks. 2) Then i noticed the bitstream has to be stored at the address 0x0 (into flash memory) for the FPGA to load well its configuration, that why i wanted to figure out how to boot Cortex-M1 not from the 0x0.

Comment: If the instructions will be stored into the flash memory , and the data and veriables will be stored int the FPGA's internal RAM blocks, so the flash memory will be read only, such that variables will be stored no into the flash memory, right? or i am mising something?

Comment: Before main(), the global variables (.data) vars are in flash and must be loaded into RAM. If you re-write flash at runtime and move vector table, you need to make sure that on second boot global variables will be loaded from flash into ram again correctly (mustn't be overwritten in flash). This is almost guaranteed to be a problem in your scenario unless you do fancy stuff in linker script to place .data somewhere else in flash. I still vote for doing anything possible to avoid using start of Flash. Any idea in my eyes will be a better idea than re-writing the start of Flash.